# Remote Desktop Connection over 2 Routers

Tags: remote-desktop

i got some routing problems, i recently installed a wireless router on my garage so i can have ethernet on my garage office, and id like to remotely access my computer, the setup is as follows:

• Default gateway Primary Router: (Modem/Router combo) coaxial input from the ISP, 192.168.0.1

• Second Router: Asus AC-1300 ( connected toPrimary router through ethernet cable) 192.168.50.xx

•  Win 10 pc (remote desktop target) connected to Second 
   Router through ethernet port

Win 10 pc has been configured to allow remote connections (configured firewall ports and configured a static ip), i also configured the secondary router to port forward the remote port to that pc, my question is how do i forward the port from the main router? It doesnt allow me to enter an ip above the 192.168.xx range

Comment: What is the make/model of the primary router?

You may want to state the gateway ip for each router, and the static ip assigned to the rdp server/host.  Where is the 2nd computer? What is its ip?

Comment: The connection is basically Router1--->Router2---->PC

Comment: Yes thanks I see that. But can you include the ip # for each device in that mapping?  Isnt there a second PC?  Where is it?  Otherwise we are shooting in the dark.

What is the gateway ip for each router?  You need to state the ip numbers to really get an idea of what the problem/solution. is

Comment: Also model numbers would be a help, to check specs. I would really update your question with this stuff ;-)

Comment: I don't understand why people who install multiple routers to extend their networks don't use the proper devices for the task. Wireless range extenders, power line networking, MoCA, etc.

Comment: Sorry, my second comment got submitted before i could edit it, im on my phone, The connection is basically Router1--->Router2---->PC, router1 i believe is a motorola, router2 is an asus ac-1300, i got both ips of the routers, and the pc target for remote desk, that is not the issue, the issue is that i cannot forward the port from the first router as it wont let me enter 192.168.xx.xx, where "x" is the remainder of the ip of the remote desktop pc/host

Comment: Again, you're doing this the hard way. If you need to extend the range of your wireless network why don't you just use a wireless range extender?

Answer (score 2):

Your router isn't allowing you to port forward to an IP address that isn't on it's local network - that's typical for a home router. You've hooked the routers up wrong. This is not how you should extend your network. You created two independent networks when you should be extending the existing network out to your garage. Also, why are you using a router out in the garage? Why aren't you just using a network switch? Or do you need wireless too? There are so many problems with the way you have it setup.

Set your network up exactly how I answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1232080/will-connecting-extra-routers-to-my-main-router-increase-the-load-on-all/1232106#1232106

Comment: yea i can see that now, i tried doing as you said, but the router pops up an error "WAN and LAN should have different IP and subnet mask network"  should the WAN of ROUTER2 have a static IP as well?

Comment: The WAN port / interface of ROUTER2 is not used at all. It should be set to DHCP (Obtain automatically) and then you might need to power cycle the router with the WAN port unplugged so that it does NOT obtain an IP address.